# Re-using methods with GetComponent

Tags: unity-game-engine

In a script called `MenuScript`, I have the following methods for loading a new scene with a click sound when the start button is pressed:

```
/// Play a sound and change the scene.
public void LoadLevel(string sceneName)
{
    audioSource.Play();
    StartCoroutine(LoadSceneAsync(sceneName));
}


/// Change the scene (load the level).
private IEnumerator LoadSceneAsync(string levelName)
{ 
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
    Application.LoadLevel(levelName);
}


/// Start the simulation once the Start Button is clicked.
public void startSimulation()
{                   
    LoadLevel("mainScene");         
}
```

I did this instead of just using `Application.LoadLevel("mainScene");`

Of course, I keep the game object that has this script attached to from getting destroyed in the `Awake`:

```
void Awake()
{           
    DontDestroyOnLoad(GameObject.Find("Menu Manager"));
}
```

Now... in this loaded new scene, I would like to do the same for loading **yet another scene**, using the same functions above that exist in the `MenuScript` script, so I wrote the following:

```
void Start()
{
    GameObject menuManager = GameObject.Find("Menu Manager");
    MenuScript menuScript = menuManager.GetComponent<MenuScript>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
        menuScript.LoadLevel("finalScene");
}
```

However, the `menuScript.LoadLevel` part is highlighted red. What am I doing wrong? Is this a good way of using those methods? Could someone please help me understand what I am missing, or if perhaps there is a better way of doing this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access `menuScript`  variable, which is local variable of `Start()` function, from another function. To fix this, declare `menuScript` variable as class variable. Here is code example:

```
private MenuScript menuScript;

void Start()
{
    GameObject menuManager = GameObject.Find("Menu Manager");
    menuScript = menuManager.GetComponent<MenuScript>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
        menuScript.LoadLevel("finalScene");
}
```